# Unroot an SLCD Droid Incredible

Tags: unrooting, unrooting, unrevoked

I remember when I first rooted my SLCD Droid Incredible I had to use a special version of ClockworkMod because the original version would "Screen Brick" SLCD Incredibles.

If I were to unroot, are there any precautions I should take? Specifically following [these](http://androidforums.com/incredible-all-things-root/181255-how-downgrade-official-2-2-a.html) or similar instructions.

Although I'm sure it doesn't make a difference, I used [Unrevoked3](http://unrevoked.com/) to root my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do s-on, flash that before flashing the RUU. Other than that, just keep in mind that the RUU will wipe your phone.

Comment: Does RUU also replace ClockworkMod with the official recovery? My goal is to go back to a completely normal phone.

Comment: Yes it does. The phone will be completely stock.